# Checking, if items of one dataframe are inside a range, defined in another dataframe and have the same index

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes created from files:
[image]
[image]

And I want to check in which range made out of `DOY installed` and `DOY removed` columns are values form `Bias start` column, but it needs to be done in groups made out of matching `Station ID` index from both dfs. After that I want to create third dataframe which will consist of all columns from second df and `Receiver type` selected based on range condition. Here is desired output:

[image]

and code:

```
'input: df1, df2'
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['ABMF', 'ASTECH', 'GPS', '2008-07-15', '2009-10-15', 2008.20, 2009.29],
                    ['ABMF', 'LEICA', 'GPS+GLO', '2009-10-15', '2011-11-15', 2009.29, 2011.32],
                    ['ABMF', 'SEPT', 'GPS+GLO', '2011-11-15', '2015-04-28', 2011.32, 2015.12],
                    ['ABMF', 'TRIMBLE', 'GPS', '2015-04-28', '2019-04-15', 2015.12, 2019.11],
                    ['ZIMM', 'ASTECH', 'GPS', '1993-05-01', '1997-08-06', 1993.12, 1997.22],
                    ['ZIMM', 'SEPT', 'GPS', '1997-08-06', '2003-08-12', 1997.22, 2003.22],
                    ['ZIMM', 'TRIMBLE', 'GPS', '2003-08-12', '2015-04-27', 2003.22, 2015.12]],
                    columns=['Station ID','Receiver type','Satellite system','Date installed', 
                    'Date removed','DOY installed','DOY removed'])
df1.set_index(['Station ID','Receiver type'], inplace=True)

df2 = pd.DataFrame([['ABMF', 'C1P', 'C2P', 2013.09, 2013.09, -1.25, 0.15],
                    ['ABMF', 'C2W', 'C2X', 2013.10, 2013.10, -1.1, 0.1],
                    ['ABMF', 'C2C', 'C2P', 2013.14, 2013.14, -1.115, 0.123],
                    ['ABMF', 'C2W', 'C2X', 2013.22, 2013.22, -1.23, 0.12],
                    ['ABMF', 'C2W', 'C2X', 2013.42, 2013.42, -1.7, 0.124],
                    ['ZIMM', 'C2W', 'C2X', 2013.10, 2013.10, -1.21, 0.11],
                    ['ZIMM', 'C2W', 'C2X', 2013.12, 2013.12, -1.14, 0.11],
                    ['ZIMM', 'C2W', 'C2X', 2013.14, 2013.14, -1.41, 0.31]],
                    columns=['Station ID','OBS1','OBS2','Bias start','Bias end','Value','Std'])
df2.set_index('Station ID', inplace=True)

'desired output: df3'
df3 = pd.DataFrame([['ABMF', 'C1P', 'C2P', 2013.09, 2013.09, -1.25, 0.15, 'SEPT'],
                    ['ABMF', 'C2W', 'C2X', 2013.10, 2013.10, -1.1, 0.1, 'SEPT'],
                    ['ABMF', 'C2C', 'C2P', 2013.14, 2013.14, -1.115, 0.123, 'SEPT'],
                    ['ABMF', 'C2W', 'C2X', 2013.22, 2013.22, -1.23, 0.12, 'SEPT'],
                    ['ABMF', 'C2W', 'C2X', 2013.42, 2013.42, -1.7, 0.124, 'SEPT'],
                    ['ZIMM', 'C2W', 'C2X', 2013.10, 2013.10, -1.21, 0.11, 'TRIMBLE'],
                    ['ZIMM', 'C2W', 'C2X', 2013.12, 2013.12, -1.14, 0.11, 'TRIMBLE'],
                    ['ZIMM', 'C2W', 'C2X', 2013.14, 2013.14, -1.41, 0.31, 'TRIMBLE']],
                    columns=['Station ID','OBS1','OBS2','Bias start','Bias end','Value','Std', 'Receiver type'])
df3.set_index('Station ID', inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) operation using the `by` parameter to work per StationID. Note that to perform this operation, the columns used need to be sorted. The rest is cosmetic to fit the expected output.

```
df_ = (pd.merge_asof(
              df2.reset_index().sort_values(by='Bias start'),
              df1.reset_index().sort_values(by='DOY installed'), 
              by='Station ID',
              left_on='Bias start', right_on='DOY installed', 
              direction='backward'
              )
          [['Station ID'] + df2.columns.tolist() + ['Reciever type']]
          .sort_values(by=['Station ID', 'Bias start'])
          .set_index('Station ID')
      )
print(df_)
           OBS1 OBS2  Bias start  Bias end  Value    Std Reciever type
Station ID                                                            
ABMF        C1P  C2P     2013.09   2013.09 -1.250  0.150          SEPT
ABMF        C2W  C2X     2013.10   2013.10 -1.100  0.100          SEPT
ABMF        C2C  C2P     2013.14   2013.14 -1.115  0.123          SEPT
ABMF        C2W  C2X     2013.22   2013.22 -1.230  0.120          SEPT
ABMF        C2W  C2X     2013.42   2013.42 -1.700  0.124          SEPT
ZIMM        C2W  C2X     2013.10   2013.10 -1.210  0.110       TRIMBLE
ZIMM        C2W  C2X     2013.12   2013.12 -1.140  0.110       TRIMBLE
ZIMM        C2W  C2X     2013.14   2013.14 -1.410  0.310       TRIMBLE
```

Comment: it works just fine, but is there a way to do this when indexes does not match, for eg. if there is third index in second df only?

Comment: @MateuszPiskorski you mean if there is another station ID in df2 only? right now this station ID should still be there and type in the result will be nan

Comment: yes that is what i meant. But my problem is that my real df1 has 507 different sation ids and my df2 has 57 and as output i get `reciever type` column filled only with nan and i dont know why

Comment: @MateuszPiskorski not sure how to help here, I assume there is either a problem of matching in the names, or in the Bias start/DOY installed type of data?

Comment: I figured it out so everything is fine

Comment: So i have encountered another problem. This doen't work as axpected for me because sometimes `Reciever type` changes few times during one year and as an output and i only get last receiver that was installed during this period. How can I fix that?

Comment: @MateuszPiskorski without a reproducible example, it will be hard to find what's wrong. I suggest you to write a new question, you can still add the link to this one and explain with a reproducible example what's wrong with this method :)